# Need to update a text file with new content found in an other text file

Tags: bash, shell, text-files

hello i was update a file, removing some content from it, now that i have to new file
i want it's content back to the original file

```
    hidden=Desktop/newtodo.txt    
    do
        echo -e "$y \t $line" >> $hidden
        y=$(($y+1))
    done

    newtodo.txt > todo.txt
```

i have content in `todo.txt` i updated them in `newtodo.txt`, now i want to remove all what is in `todo.txt` and replace them with `newtodo.txt`
direct assigning is not working using >

Comment: `mv newtodo.txt todo.txt` ?

Comment: write after i posted the question i came up witht he answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use output redirection

> ```
> cat newtodo.txt > todo.txt  <br>
> ```

or 
You could rename newtodo.txt

> mv newtodo.txt todo.txt

Answer (score -1):

```
cp /dev/null $file

cat $hidden | while read line
do
    echo "$line" >> $file
done
```

Comment: Just use mv, this is all unnecessary.